# Cinnamon DE theme settings not working, 16.04 LTS Cinnamon DE 3.4

Tags: 16.04, themes, lts, cinnamon

I switched to cinnamon recently, but themes section is not showing up in settings, it opens and crashes immediately. How do we fix this? Thank you.